# Adding integers together in C but not mathematically

Tags: c

How would one go about adding integers together like this.

Say you start with 1, then you add 2. So you have 12, next add 3, so you have 123. And so on.

I would just concatenate but I'm not allowed to use strings in this program.

Comment: So, conversion to string and string concatenation? Have you heard of `sprintf`?

Comment: What your describing looks like the decimal numbering system. You know how that works? You know what happens if you multiply a number with `10`? Now think about that for a while.

Comment: make an array of integers?
if you know the maximum number of digits to be added, you can just place them in the array one after the other.

Comment: Just create them as strings and "concatenate" instead of "adding". When you have concatenated string, convert that to integer.

Comment: I would just concatenate but I'm not allowed to use strings in this program.

Comment: These kinds of assignments are for you to crack :) Put some thought on what @Someprogrammerdude said.

Answer (score 4):

Using some unusual math (based on the mechanisms of the decimal system) to make the desired variation of adding:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int number=0;
    for (i=1; i<5; ++i)
    {
        number=number*10 + i;
        printf("%d\n", number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = 4, b = 5, c = 6, d = 7;
  printf("a+b=%d\n",a*10+b);
  printf("a+b+c=%d\n",(a*10+b)*10+c);
  printf("a+b+c+d=%d\n",((a*10+b)*10+c)*10+d);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be typical case to use `realloc`

```
char *mystr = NULL;
char *temp;
char c, ch;

short count = 0;
do {
    printf("Enter character : ");
    scanf(" %c", &c); //  Better use sscanf or fgets, scanf is problematic
    temp = (char*)realloc(mystr, (++count) * sizeof *mystr);
    if (NULL != temp) {
        mystr = temp;
        mystr[count - 1] = c;
    }
    printf("Do you wish to continue: ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
} while ('y' == ch);
// Since and since you don't have a null terminated string, do
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%c", mystr[i]);

    printf("\n");
free(mystr); // Freeing the memory
getch();
```

---

<sup>**Note :** And you don't have strings in this program ;)</sup>

Comment: "don't have strings in this program" aside from strings used as formats: `"Enter character : ", " %c", ...`

Comment: Note: Alternative to `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%c", mystr[i]);

    printf("\n");` --> `printf(".*s\n", count, mystr);`